# Missing Select Keyword

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
 With A as (Select Trip, a from Table1),
      B as (Select pattern, a from Table2),
      C as (Select Trip, Pattern from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.a=Table2.a),

 Update A
 Set A.Pattern = C.Pattern
 From C
 WHERE C.TRIP = A.TRPIP
```

It gives error of Missing Select Keyword, anyone know how to solve update with CTE in oracle10g?

Comment: That is not a valid syntax in Oracle, can you explain what are you trying  to achieve here with sample data?

Comment: Hint: use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use **merge**. It will be similar to your **with**.

```
 merge into Table1 A
 using ( select a, pattern from Table2) B
 on ( A.a = B.a) 
 when matched then
   update set  A.trip = B.pattern;
```

Merge will find occurrences of **a** in **Table1** that exists on **Table2** and will replace the **Trip** by **pattern**.

Example is here :
[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d817a/2/0)